# Why CollectionViewCell animation disappear?

Tags: ios, swift

I add animation to the collectionViewCell , but when i scroll the CollectionView, the animation of the cell  disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply add [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; inside the animation block, like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:((self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.width - self.collectionView.contentOffset.x) / 75) delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState) animations:^{
            self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.width, 0);
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but it's not my wants. The focus is the reused cell can't added  animation again.